# Fusionar 2 tablas, por una características en Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Os comento no sé cómo realizar una unió de 2 pandas.

El primer pandas es una tabla con entradas de datos, una de esas columnas es "day" que tiene la fecha en el formato datetime64[ns].

#### Dataframe de entradas

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
                    'entrada': ['e1', 'e2', 'e3'],
                    'day': ['2023-01-02', '2023-01-02', '2023-02-23'],
                  'other1': ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc'],
                   'other2': ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc']
                  })
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El otro pandas es una tabla con información relevante a un día en concreto.

#### Dataframe de días

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'day': ['2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-02-23'],
                  'altitude': ['9', '9', '9'],
                   'sun': ['11', '12', '23']
                  })
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Digamos que P1 tiene entradas y en cada entrada guarda la fecha y P2 es información de lo que ocurre en una fecha.
En ambos pandas el campo "day" tiene el mismo **formato (datetime64[ns]).**

Mi duda es: **¿Como puedo hacer que para cada entrada de P1, busque en el campo "day" de P2 y añada sus características.**

#### Resultado esperado

#Dataframe resultado

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                'entrada': ['e1', 'e2', 'e3'],
                'day': ['2023-01-02', '2023-01-02', '2023-02-23'],
                'other1': ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc'],
                'other2': ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc'],
                'altitude': ['9', '9', '9'],
                'sun': ['11', '11', '23']
                  })
df
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado tanto merge como join, pero no he obtenido el resultado deseado, dejo las ideas:

```
pd.merge(df_dia, df_aparcamiento, how = "right",left_on = ["day"] , right_on = ["day"], copy=False)

df = df_aparcamiento.join(df_dia, how = "outer", lsuffix='day', rsuffix='day', sort = True)
```

Solo se me ocurre crear un método manual que cree un diccionario para cada día y luego recorrer todas las entradas concatenando las características correspondientes.

Cualquier ayuda se agradecería, gracias.

### Edición

Gracias por vuestra ayuda, la verdad que así sí que se entiende más las duda.
Y sí, el merge funciona correctamente, lo que ocurría es que al faltar días en df_2, me aparecían valores nulos, pero tiene todo el sentido del mundo.

Vuelvo a repetirme, muchas gracias.

Comment: Buen día, por favor oprime [edit] y agrega algunas filas de tus `dataframes` como texto, no como imagen y también un ejemplo como texto del `dataframe` que deseas obtener para entender mejor lo que deseas hacer.

Comment: Para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte, necesitará hacer pruebas con tus datos o con unos semejantes a los tuyos. No es necesario el dataframe completo, bastan unas filas, pero que muestren la misma estructura y los mismos tipos de datos (es importante saber si la fecha está almacenada como cadena o como datetime, por ejemplo). Una forma en la que puedes proporcionar esta información es compartir los ficheros de los que lees los dataframes (o parte de ellos) a través de un enlace, y añadir a la pregunta el código con que los lees.

Comment: Muchas gracias por los datos; una pregunta muy bien formulada y completa. Pero resulta que el merge sí que da el resultado buscado. Acabo de probar con tus dataframes el comando `df = pd.merge(df_2, df_1, how = "right",left_on = ["day"] , right_on = ["day"], copy=False)` y, salvo por el orden de las columnas, sale exactamente el resultado que pides. Si es el orden de las columnas lo que te molesta puedes hacer seguidamente `df = df[["entrada", "day", "other1", "other2", "altitude", "sun"]]`

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como indica [abulafia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7123/abulafia)... la respuesta es:

```
df = pd.merge(df_2, df_1, how = "right",left_on = ["day"] , right_on = ["day"], copy=False)
```

El código completo seria:

```
import pandas as pd


df_1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'entrada': ['e1', 'e2', 'e3'],
                      'day': ['2023-01-02', '2023-01-02', '2023-02-23'],
                      'other1': ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc'],
                      'other2': ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc'] } )

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'day': ['2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-02-23'],
                     'altitude': ['9', '9', '9'],
                     'sun': ['11', '12', '23'] } )



df = pd.merge(df_2, df_1, how = "right",left_on = ["day"] , right_on = ["day"], copy=False)

df = df[["entrada", "day", "other1", "other2", "altitude", "sun"]]

print(df)


'''
  entrada         day other1 other2 altitude sun
0      e1  2023-01-02   aaaa   aaaa        9  11
1      e2  2023-01-02   bbbb   bbbb        9  11
2      e3  2023-02-23   cccc   cccc        9  23
'''
```